# Kabsch algorithm for units vector

Tags: vectors, 3d, rotations

I have two sets of unit 3D **vectors**. Those two sets are related by an unknown 3D rotation matrix. I want to estimate this 3D rotation matrix. As far as I read, Kabsch algorithm is great tool to find 3D rotation between two sets of 3D **Points**. However, it does not seem to work with vectors.

I have implemented it in MATLAB and test it with 3D **points**. Everything was perfect. it estimates the correct rotation matrix and an almost 0 translation vector(something at scale 1e-7). However, when I test it with unit vectors, it produces a rotation matrix around Z only and a translation vector with high scale which seems incorrect for me.

I suspect that there is a basic difference between a 3D point and a 3D vector that I did not take it in consideration.

What did I miss? Is it possible to use Kabsch algorithm with 3D vectors?

**Edit:**

My vectors are scale-less direction vectors from the same origin (both sets have the same origina which is 0,0,0).

Each vector represents infinity 3d points (I do not know where the actual point lays. However, after the rotation is applied, each pair of vectors should lays at the exact same ray so all the 3D points represented by a vector v1 should be identical to the 3D Points lays on v1'

Comment: Why not use Gram–Schmidt process to orthonormalize the vector set, so that you have two full basis sets (orientation matrices) $\mathbf{R}_1$ and $\mathbf{R}_2$?  Then, the rotation from the first to the second is $\mathbf{R}_2\mathbf{R}_1^{-1} = \mathbf{R}_2\mathbf{R}_1^T$ (because for the orthonormal basis set matrix, its inverse is its transpose).

Comment: @Blabbo the Verbose What I don't understand in the question of the asker asking for the difference between point and vectors is that he doesn't mention the **"registration"** (at least composed from a translation) in order that the points of the two clouds have a common origin (usually one uses a translation in order that the barycenters of clouds 1 and 2 coincide)

Comment: @JeanMarie: True.  Even the Kabsch algorithm requires that to be done (and the combined operation can be called [Procrustes analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrustes_analysis) (with various constraints).  Humam Helfawi: 3D vectors are either positions or displacements.  If the vectors represent displacement from origin, or from any common point, they can be treated exactly like positions.  If each vector represents displacement from a separate point, you need to pairwise sum the displacement and reference point, so that they represent location (or displacement from a common point).

Comment: Thanks for your time and  reply. I have edit the question with more details.